# Do mutable states stack in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my app, I need to store a map that associates a specific user with a list of messages sent to the current user.  The original data structure looks like this:
`val friendMessages = LinkedHashMap<User,ArrayList<Message>>()`.  However, with moving to compose, I need to make sure that the view will recompose either size of the map changes and when any ArrayList in the map changes.  I thought about doing somthing like this, `mutableStateMapOf<User, SnapshotStateList<Message>>()` and then initializing each list with mutableStateListOf(),  but I dont know if the state changes will propgate through the containing map.

Comment: I seems you need a model that has the user and the list of message of the user and then pass that as a list `friendMessages = List<Wrapper>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can stack MutableState in each other and scope that reads that State will recompose no matter in which data structure it is, except you will lose ordering of LinkedHashMap using SnapshotStateMap but you can order via index or order param.

You can add users, set messages for selected user or remove user from map and as in gif below recomposition will take effect.

[image]

I made a sample to show what you suggested works.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun TestNestedStructure() {
    val map = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<User, SnapshotStateList<Message>>()
    }

    var user by remember {
        mutableStateOf<User?>(null)
    }

    var userName by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    var message by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 20.dp)
    ) {
        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                value = userName,
                onValueChange = {
                    userName = it
                }
            )

            Button(onClick = {
                map[User(userName)] = mutableStateListOf()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Add User")
            }
        }

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                value = message,
                onValueChange = {
                    message = it
                }
            )

            Button(onClick = {
                user?.let {
                    map[it]?.run {
                        add(Message(text = message))
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Add Message")
            }
        }

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
        ) {

            val users = map.keys.toList()

            items(
                items = users,
                key = { item ->
                    item.uuid
                }
            ) { currentUser: User ->
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .shadow(2.dp)
                        .border(2.dp, getRandomColor())
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clickable {
                            user = currentUser
                        }
                        .padding(8.dp)
                ) {
                    Row {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                            text = currentUser.name
                        )
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            map.remove(currentUser)
                        }) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Remove, contentDescription = "remove")
                        }
                    }
                    map[currentUser]?.forEach { message ->
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp),
                            text = message.text
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data classes

```
data class Message(val text: String)

data class User(val name: String, val uuid: UUID = UUID.randomUUID())
```

Also added border to see recomposition with a random color changes on each recomposition with

```
fun getRandomColor() =  Color(
    red = Random.nextInt(256),
    green = Random.nextInt(256),
    blue = Random.nextInt(256),
    alpha = 255
)
```